# How to update a DataGridView in a Windows form when the end-user adds selection criteria

Tags: c#, database

I have a data grid view that shows all rows of a particular database table on a Windows form.  Above the grid, I have text fields with corresponding buttons that a user can use to narrow down the data grid view by various criteria, such as By Customer Number, By Order Number, etc...  I haven't been able to figure out how to accomplish this.

I've tried many examples I've found online, the most recent resulting the code below.

```
OleDbConnection connection = SerialsDatabaseDB.GetConnection();
      string selectStatement
          = "Select * "
          + "FROM Orders "
          + "WHERE CustomerNumber = @CustomerNumber";
      OleDbCommand selectCommand =
          new OleDbCommand(selectStatement, connection);
      selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerNumber", custNumber);

      OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = 
          new OleDbDataAdapter(selectStatement, connection);
      DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("OrdersByCustomer");
      connection.Open();
      dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "OrdersByCustomer");
      connection.Close();
      dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet;
      dataGridView1.DataMember = "OrdersByCustomer";
```

Currently, I'm getting a "No value given for one or more required parameters" on the dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "OrdersByCustomer"); line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your code with this change

```
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand);
```

`Ole​DbData​Adapter` has 4 constructors. One of them takes an instance of `OleDbCommand`. In your code you are creating it but you are not passing it into relevant constructor. The parameter you created and added to the `selectCommand` is just remaining unused. The exception you are getting is the result of this.